# Using C# generic class with Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, generics, neo4j, neo4jclient

I would like to create a generic class that creates nodes for multiple node class types. 
See example below:

```
public NodeReference<TObject> CreateObject(TObject objectType)
        {  
            NodeReference<TObject> nodeReference = 0;
            nodeReference = clientConnection.Create<TObject> (objectType);
            return nodeReference;
        }
```

However I keep getting the following error
[image]

Comment: I believe Its a generic Object in c#, i think, im not too sure. Saw it being used in an example in a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your method like so:

```
public NodeReference<TObject> CreateObject(TObject objectType)
    where TObject: class //<-- NEW BIT HERE
{  
    NodeReference<TObject> nodeReference = 0;
    nodeReference = clientConnection.Create<TObject> (objectType);
    return nodeReference;
}
```

by putting `where TObject: class` you are saying that the type of 'TObject' must always be a class (or reference type). You may need to also put:

```
where TObject: class, new()
```

but I can't remember - the `new()` bit means that the class has to have a constructor with no arguments (which can be the default constructor).

Comment: Is `where TObject: class` the way you reference the class as suggest in the error message?

Comment: It's a generic parameter constraint. It means that the type parameter must be a reference type. Your error message indicates you want a reference type.

Comment: @MikeBarnes Yes - you have Reference Types and Value Types, reference types are classes, value types are things like `int`, `double` etc. Generally - if you can set it to `null` (`MyObj o = null;`) then it's a reference type, doing the same to a value type will give a compile time error (`int i = null;`).